# login with google not responding

Tags: android

I wrote a program of Android and push on git. after reboot the (formating) the lap, I pull my code all function are working but login with google is not working.
I registered my SHA1 key also.

Comment: Please update your code so it's easy to read.

Comment: Expect a visit from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).